# Headless ChromeDriver freezing when loading a page

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I have a weird problem.

What happens is that even though the program runs fine when disabling headless mode, it <s>freezes</s> slows down immensely (takes more than 30 seconds to load google) when headless.

The test that I run is the same for both ChromeDrivers (headless/non headless).

<strike>And they are like so: take time A, load page, take time B, C = B-A, print "It took C ms to load page!" (this is pseudocode, I think that posting actual code is uneccessary here).</strike>

EDIT:

This is the full blown code to test this.

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Put your path here");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless"); // I only comment this out when I disable headless

    HashMap<String, Object> images = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    images.put("images", 2);

    HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values", images);

    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

    DesiredCapabilities chromeCaps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    chromeCaps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCaps);

    int a = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    int b = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    int c = b - a;
    System.out.println("Hey the page loaded in " + c + "ms!");
}
```

EDIT 2:

Okay, found something even more weird. The page loads, but takes a long time (over 30000 ms). This does not happen in non headless mode (under 1000ms)